# Fatal error: Call to undefined method weather::get()

Tags: php

I was trying to make weather based PHP script to show weather related data.But,I'm facing this error message

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method weather::get()**

Would you please let me know how can i fix this or what was my problem??You can check out my code here:

```
<?php
include 'weather.php';
$t_weather = new weather();
$info = $t_weather->get('New York');
echo "Current temperature in {$info[0]['location']} is: {$info[0]['current_condition']['temperature']['f']} °F";
 ?>
```

This is weather.php:

```
<?php
class weather {
 // API data
 private $API_NAME   = 'weather';
 private $API_KEY    = '***********';
 }
 ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to read the docs for your weather api and implement a `get` method that calls the api with the passed parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well your `weather` class doesn't have a method named get. Are you using someone else's class to do this? You should have something like:

```
class weather {
    // API data
    private $API_NAME   = 'weather';
    private $API_KEY    = '***********';

    public function get($location) {
        // code that gets the weather for $location
    }
}
```

Comment: here is the tutorial link i followed:http://codecanyon.net/item/multi-weather-a-4weatherapi-php-plugin/full_screen_preview/1004186

Comment: Sorry, it looks like that is a paid product. You'll need to buy it and follow the rest of the instructions on that page or find a tutorial - there are a few out there using free weather services.

Comment: In fact, here's a really simple one using Google's weather API http://komunitasweb.com/2009/09/showing-the-weather-with-php-and-google-weather-api/

Comment: Ros,Would you like to suggest me some free service??